# Nodejs on Windows, npm doesn't install modules from registry

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having a problem with my new installation of Node.js (windows 64 bit).
I'm trying to install the express module inside a project of mine but I can't work it out.

I type this command :

```
npm install -g express
```

However this is the result of the command

> ├── escape-html@1.0.1 ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2 ├── cookie-signature@1.0.5 ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 ├── cookie@0.1.2 ├── range-parser@1.0.2 ├── finalhandler@0.3.2 ├── fresh@0.2.4 ├── media-typer@0.3.0 ├── methods@1.1.0 ├── vary@1.0.0 ├── parseurl@1.3.0 ├── serve-static@1.7.1 ├── content-disposition@0.5.0 ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3 ├── depd@1.0.0 ├── qs@2.3.3 ├── on-finished@2.1.1 (ee-first@1.1.0) ├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2) ├── etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1) ├── send@0.10.1 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11) ├── proxy-addr@1.0.4 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.5) ├── accepts@1.1.4 (negotiator@0.4.9, mime-types@2.0.4) └── type-is@1.5.4 (mime-types@2.0.4)

It's the list of dependecies needed by express but there's no download of them.

The first time I tried to use npm I had this problem (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4808)

There were many solutions to solve it, one of them consist in disable the layer ssl for the connection to the npm online registry but I don't think there's a connection between this solution (that I applied) and the problem.

Thank you in advance,

Luca

Comment: It looks like they were downloaded just fine.  What makes you think they weren't?  And, why are you installing Express globally?

Comment: The directory express doesn't appear in the node_modules directory of my project. I would like to install it globally in order to use it in other projects.

Comment: It won't appear in the node_modules directory of your project... you installed it globally.  Don't install it globally.  Keep a separate copy for each project.  This is important since you'll want to have separate versions at some point later on.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry... I have misunderstood a concept of a guide I'm following about Node.js
However it works...

Answer (score 0):

The `express` module should be installed on a per project basis.

```
npm install --save express
```